# Euclidean Distance for csv file

Tags: java, arrays

I have a CSV file , the first column is ID and the other are the measurement, how can i calculate the euclidean distance for the data.i read the files using Readcsv, then i tried to calculate the distance but i have error. i just need to read the column as double data calculate distance  and separate the ID from value of X1,X2. print each distance with its ID.

```
     double[][] Data = ReadCSV.read("C:\\Users\\navien\\Desktop\\dataset3.csv", 263, false);

  double Sum = 0.0;
    double distances;

    for(int i=0;i<Data.length;i++) {
        for ( int j=i+1; j<Data[0].length;j++){
       Sum = Sum + Math.pow((Data[i][j]-Data[i][j]),2.0);    // the file compost of three column
    }
    }

    distances = Math.sqrt(Sum);
```

Comment: what is the results of Data[i][j]-Data[i][j]?

Comment: What is your error? Also add a sample of your file.

Comment: I do not have any result its just error ,  how can i separate the ID column  and calculate the Euclidean Distance ??

Comment: Are your columns ID, x, y?

Comment: Yes the first column is ID and then X,Y  or X1,X2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
 Sum = Sum + Math.pow((Data[i][j]-Data[i][j]),2.0)
```

you subtract equal numbers `(Data[i][j]-Data[i][j])` so the result will be always 0.

This method computes euclidean distance where each column in file represents coordinates of the point.

```
public static void euclidianDistanceFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("ID")) continue;
        String[] arr = line.split(",");
        String name = arr[0];
        double p = Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
        double q = Double.parseDouble(arr[2]);
        double res = Math.sqrt((p - q) * (p - q));
        System.out.println(name + ": " + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i express the column two and three in the csv file and calculate the distance between them ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange your line reader to store the x and y of the previous row of data (say x1, y1), and x and y of the current row (say x2, y2)

Then, an application of Pythagoras' theorem, gives

```
Sum = Sum + Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))
```

`Sum` will then be the length of the jagged line connecting the points in the order they appear in your file.

Comment: Bathsheb ,  please can we work directly on the Data which is double type and calculate the distance , this is what iam trying in my code , not reading it as string file ?

Comment: You've accepted the incorrect answer which somewhat dampens my enthusiasm for the project :-)

Comment: Kindly i just want  to learn and find solution.